# How to write a TypeScript definition of a tuple that spreads itself?

Tags: typescript

```
type Attributes = Record<string, string>;

type NodeSnapshot =
  | string
  | [string, Attributes, ...NodeSnapshot]
```

In theory, I would expect the above to work. However, it is giving an error:

> Type alias 'NodeSnapshot' circularly references itself.ts(2456)

The example data that could be represented by this variable:

```
// string
const s1 = 'Example Domain';
// [string, Attributes, string]
const s2 = ['H1', {}, 'Example Domain'];
// [string, Attributes, [string, Attributes, string]]
const s3 = [
  'DIV',
  {},
  [
    'H1',
    {},
    'Example Domain'
  ]
];
// [string, Attributes, [string, Attributes, string], string, [string, Attributes, string]]
const s4 = [
  'DIV',
  {},
  ['H1', {}, 'Example Domain'],
  '\n',
  ['A', { href: 'https://www.iana.org/domains/example' }, 'Hello, World!'],
];
```

Comment: If `...NodeSnapShot` is changed to `...NodeSnapShot[]`, the error is gone and it seems that s1, s2, s3 and s4 all satisfy it. (e.g. `const s2 = ['H1', {}, 'Example Domain'] satisfies NodeSnapshot;` )

Comment: _ah_, I totally missed `[]`! The circular reference error threw me off here. Adding `[]` is the correct answer here. Thank you!

Comment: ^^^ That must be it; I was trying to interpret the type definition

Comment: You can read more about tuple types and their syntax in the handbook: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types